# Div within a modal isn't always firing scroll events on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, scroll

I have the following hierarchy and styles in a Vue component within an application:

```js
<template lang="pug">
    my-modal-component.modal-container
        template(v-slot:content)
            swiper.swiper(
                :options="swiperOptions"
                ref="feedback-swiper"
                @slideChangeTransitionEnd="onTransitionEnd"
                @slideNextTransitionEnd="onSlideNextTransitionEnd"
                @slidePrevTransitionEnd="onSlidePrevTransitionEnd")
                swiper-slide.page-container(ref="modal" @scroll.native="handleScroll")
                    .content-root(:class="transitioning ? 'disable-interaction' : ''")
                        div
                            .main-text Main Text
                            pill-selector
                        .additional-details-container
                            .main-text Main Text
                            textarea.additionalDetails
                            .char-count number of cur chars
                        .contact-me
                            input.input(type="checkbox" v-model="contactMe")
                            label.label(@click="toggleContactMe")pls help
                .swiper-pagination.pagination(slot="pagination")
                .swiper-button-prev.prev-slide(slot="button-prev" @click="goToPreviousSlide()")
                .swiper-button-next.next-slide(slot="button-next" @click="goToNextSlide()")
            .button-container
                my-button.main-button SUBMIT
</template>

.modal-container {
    color: color(brown);

    .button-container {
        padding-bottom: 30px;

        .main-button {
            visibility: hidden;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .hidden {
            visibility: hidden;
        }
    }

    .page-container {
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        overflow-y: auto;

        .content-root {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            height: 1000px;
        }
    }
}
```

The `handleScroll` function captures the `@scroll.native` event every time on all desktop operating systems with all browsers as well as Android devices.

However, on all iOS devices, the `@scroll.native` event is only firing *sometimes*. **This leads to scroll not always working**.

I have tried:

- Locking the component and body behind it with different methods
- Removing all other instances of `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` from the application
- Implementing https://github.com/willmcpo/body-scroll-lock
- All sorts of hierarchy + css change combinations involving `overflow-y` and `-webkit-overflow-scrolling`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was only reproducible in iOS simulators. In real iOS devices the problem did not exist. This is the first instance I've come across where the simulator has differed in behavior from actual devices.